# Problems passing Post Paramters using Perl to Restful Java API

Tags: java, perl, rest

I am calling a rest service written in java from Perl.

```
@POST
@Path("/updategrid")
private void updategrid(@FormParam Grid grid);

Class Column{
private String col;
private String val;
//constructors and setters
}

Class Grid{
private String name;
private List<Column> columns;
//constructors and setters
}
```

I am trying to pass the post call paramters in Perl

```
$httpClient->request(host/updateGrid, {grid=>{name=>'temp', columns=>[{col=>'A',val=>'B'}]}})
```

I am getting error as Grid has no constructor with Single string parameter. But when I remove columns parameter things are fine. So what is right way to pass to list attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `@QueryForm` annotation but it seems like it tries to initialize a `Grid` object using the Json string you passes instead of using this string to serialize. Put the annotation `@RequestBody` on `updateGrid` method instead of the `@QueryForm` annotation and it should work.

Comment: Try what I suggested. Also make sure you have the jackson jars in your path.

Comment: Hmm. But the thing is if I do $httpClient->request(host/updateGrid, {grid=>{name=>'temp'}}) it works. So javax.ws.rs.@FormParam shoould be fine I think.

Comment: I guess you're right. Try changing the type of columns to `Column[]` instead of `List<Column>`.